# Using innerHTML to detect the number of occurrences of a character?

Tags: javascript

I've been using this code to detect elements in a table that contain a semicolon and then change the background colour:

```
var x = document.getElementsByTagName("TD");
var i=0;
for (i=0;i<x.length;i++) {
    if (x[i].className=="ms-vb-title") {
        if (x[i].innerHTML.indexOf(";") != -1) {
            x[i].style.cssText="background-color:#ccc !important;";
        }
    }
}
```

But I now want to change the colour based on the number of occurrences of the semicolon, so for example less than 2 would highlight red, between 2-4 would highlight orange and more than 4 would highlight green... is this achievable by modifying the existing code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `match`to know the number of occurences:

```
('str1;str2;str3;str4'.match(/;/g) || []).length;
```

The `|| []` it's for when there isn't any element so it gives to length an empty array ('cause `match` returns `null`)

Answer (score 5):

You can use `.split` to generate an array of chars at the length of the amount of chars to split (in your case `;`).

```
var a = ';;;;testtest;test;test;te;;st;;test;test;;';
var b = a.split(';');
var numOfSemicolons = b.length;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this one

```
var x = document.getElementsByTagName("TD");
var i = 0;
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if (x[i].className == "ms-vb-title") {
        var count = (x[i].innerHTML.match(/;/g) || []).length;
        if(count < 2) {
            x[i].style.cssText = "background-color:red !important;";
        }
        else if(count < 4) {
            x[i].style.cssText = "background-color:orange !important;";
        }
        else if(count >= 4) {
            x[i].style.cssText = "background-color:green !important;";
        }
        else

    }
}
```

Comment: there's an extra opening bracket after "var count = " but this works well otherwise! :)

Answer (score 0):

Step1: Find the number of occurences of semi colon
Step2: Add the color based on the count, say less than 2 occurence then red and so on.

Simpler way but costliest approach
Iterate the content and get the count and then iterate it again to add the colors

Answer (score 0):

assuming elems is an array containing your TDs, which you can get via `getElementeBy<x>` or something like `$("td .<class>")`, this might do what you want to accomplish:

```
for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++){
count = elems[i].innerHTML.split(';') - 1 ;
switch(count){
    case 0:
    case 1:
    case 2:
      elems[i].style.cssText="background-color:#C00 !important;";
    break;

    case 3:
    case 4:
    elems[i].style.cssText="background-color:#F60 !important;";
    break;

    default:
    elems[i].style.cssText="background-color:#0C0 !important;";
    break;
    }
}
```